# Why is 1.4 - 1.3 == 0.9999+ but 0.4 - 0.3 == 1.000000003

Tags: decimal-expansion, floating-point

I'm not sure if this is a maths question or a programming question or a how-does-your-computer-work question. Sorry about that.

I remember from university that 0.999999 ... == 1 since 1 - 0.999999 ... == 0.00000 ... == 0

But then this is non-trivial in programming languages.

In python3, 0.4-0.3 == 0.10000000000000003 and 1.4 - 1.3 == 0.09999999999999987 and so they are not in fact equivalent. R works slightly differently. And so on.

If I wanted to understand this, where should I start?

Comment: Obviously these last two equations are wrong, may be You should ask this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or at a similar site

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a nice quick read about floating point arithmetic.

Comment: I rather doubt that there is a difference between python and R, as they use the same floating point data type in the background. What you likely observed is a difference in the display format the identical data, if it was rounded to 6 or 10 or to 17 digits.

Comment: The other default link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because of how floating point works on computers. Some numbers are infinitely repeating when written in binary, which is what the computers use, so there's bound to be an error in the calculation, unless you use powers of 2.